# Get all diagonal elements of a List

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 2-D array of strings where I am trying to find all the diagonal elements of each element.

For example:

Input:

```
ABCD
PRAT
KITA
ANDY
```

Output:

```
{
{ { "ARTY" } },
{ { "BAA" }, { "BP" } },
...
}
```

Explanation,

- The diagonal elements of the element at (0, 0) are "ARTY"
- The diagonal elements of the elements at (0, 1) are "BAA" from the right and "BP" from the left.
  and so on.

I know that diagonals increase symettrically but I am unable to find a logic to get all the diagonals of each and every element.

Here's the code I am trying:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[,] grid = {
        {   "A", "B", "C", "D"  },
        {    "P", "R", "A", "T" },
        {    "K", "I", "T", "A" },
        {    "A", "N", "D", "Y" }
    };
}

public static IEnumerable<string> FindAllDirectionWords(string[,] grid, int curRow, int curCol, int numRows, int numCols)
{
            // Find primary diagonal now
            string primaryDiagonalWord = string.Empty;
            for (int i = curRow, j = curCol; i < numRows && j < numCols; i++, j++)
                primaryDiagonalWord += grid[i, j];
            yield return primaryDiagonalWord;


            // Find secondary diagonal now
            string secondaryDiagonalWord = string.Empty;
            for (int i = curRow, j = curCol; i < numRows && j < numCols; i++, j++)
                secondaryDiagonalWord += grid[i, j];
            yield return secondaryDiagonalWord;
}
```

Comment: What about the element `(2,1)`? Do you want the upper diagonals `"P"` and `"A","D"` also?

Comment: @ja72 You mean third row second index right ?

Comment: Yes, I mean from the letter `I` in the 3rd row and 2nd column.

Comment: PS. `int numRows, int numCols` are not needed as arguments as they can be extracted from the `grid` using the `.GetLength()` method.

Comment: @ja72 yeah I want both the diagonals

Comment: @ja72 will it recompute `.GetLength()` everytime like the `IEnumberable` `.Count()` method or is it a `O(1)` access, if its a `O(1)` access then I will refactor my code surely.

Comment: Do you mean all four diagonals? starting from `I` going Northwest = `P`, Northeast = `AD`, Southwest = `A` and Southeast = `D`? or two diagonals, `DAIA` and `PID`. It depends if you want the target letter included or not.

Comment: @ja72 1) The target letter must be included 2) Yes all the diagonals

Comment: ok. also if you are concerned about speed (is `.GetLength()` expensive?) then you should not use `+` for strings in `primaryDiagonalWord += grid[i, j];` Keep an array of strings and use `string.Join()` or use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Write code here:
        var grid = new string[,] {
            {  "A", "B", "C", "D" },
            {  "P", "R", "A", "T" },
            {  "K", "I", "T", "A" },
            {  "A", "N", "D", "Y" }};

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", grid.FindDiagonalWords(2, 1)));
        // (2,1) "I" => "PID|DAIA"
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> FindDiagonalWords(this string[,] grid, int row, int column)
    {
        int numRows = grid.GetLength(0);
        int numCols = grid.GetLength(1);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            int j = (i-row)+column;
            if (j>=0 && j<numCols)
            {
                sb.Append(grid[i, j]);
            }
        }
        yield return sb.ToString();

        sb.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            int j = row+column-i;
            if (j>=0 && j<numCols)
            {
                sb.Append(grid[i, j]);
            }
        }
        yield return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked the [C++ source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/b271aff1fa54c1385143f3b45c1bf3af01c901cd/src/vm/object.h#L647) of `coreclr` for the implementation of `.GetLength()` which calls `GetBoundsPtr()`. It does not look like an expensive operation. It essentially looks up a cached value for the dimension lengths.